# How do you usually use these three words "image, photo, picture" in the web content?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

This might be an odd question.

Currently, I am writing a website documentation. And the content includes many words such as image, photo, picture.

I am a bit confused on using it as which one have to be photo and which one have to be image.

For a native speaker, do you really care on it's meaning?

Comment: The terms tend to be used somewhat loosely.  All refer to an individual graphic of some sort, rather than a page containing a collection of components.  They refer to something that if stored individually, would be in one of the graphic or image file formats.  Generally, "photo" refers to a photograph, what would come out of a camera.  "Image" and "picture" are used pretty interchangeably.  They refer more broadly to anything of a graphic nature as differentiated from a text document.  In addition to photos, this could include such things like artwork or graphics, scans of things, graphs, etc.

Comment: @fixer1234 you forgot to mention snapshots, sketches, portraits and drawings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Image - is mostly something that is represented or something that represents something, also a replica of something.
2. Photo - a photo is a photograph (an image taken by a camera). The tricky thing is that a photo is always an image or a picture but a picture or an image may or may not be a photo.
3. Picture - is mostly something that is painted. Comes from the word **"[pictura](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=picture)"** *(Latin)*

Mostly **Image** and **Picture** are close synonyms. While **photo** is a relatively close synonym but mostly always means an image taken by a camera.

Comment: If you are referring to web content then "image" is the best choice.

Comment: This looks pretty good to me, but I'm not the only one who forgot to mention snapshots, sketches, portraits and drawings.  :-)  +1